# How to disable next button in a custom active step using ResearchKit in Swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, button, researchkit

I am very new to ResearchKit and I have just created my own custom active step along with a view controller and I need the next button to be disabled for a short period of time. I am not sure how to accomplish this at the moment. I discovered I could change the title, but I cannot disable the button as I could with the cancelButtonItem in the navigation bar. For example, to disable the cancel button like this

```
cancelButtonItem.enabled = false
```

Is there something like that for the next button in a active step? If so can someone give me an example of such?

Comment: If you can take a look one of the example: https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/master/ResearchKit/ActiveTasks/ORKWalkingTaskStepViewController.m    I think continue button is not showing up by default. I suggest you posting a issue on the Github site.

Comment: Well if it helps get the point across I want to have the continue button to appear or to be accessible after a certain amount of time has passed. I want it to not be accessible before that duration has been reached. Sorry I am a little new to iOS development and I don't know Objective-C as well as I do Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I found only hack way how to hide it:

```
for subview in self.view.subviews {
    for subview1 in subview.subviews {
        for subview2 in subview1.subviews {
            for subview3 in subview2.subviews {

                if let button = subview3 as? UIButton {
                    button.hidden = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, four loops? Seems like it works though. Thanks! (Sorry for the late response)